# facing issue regarding fetching data from a specific column from sqlite in swift

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, swift4

while working on iOS app.. I am facing a problem while fetching a data from sqlite...
below is the code which I am using for fetching the data from database...

```
func getQazaNmazdata() -> [QazaDB]
    {
        var dbData = [QazaDB]()
        let qstring = "select Counter from Qaza"
        var queryStatement: OpaquePointer? = nil
        // 1
        if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, qstring, -1, &queryStatement, nil) == SQLITE_OK {
            let data = QazaDB()
            while sqlite3_step(queryStatement) == SQLITE_ROW
            {
                let counter = sqlite3_column_int(queryStatement, 0)
                data.counter = Int(counter)
                dbData.append(data)
            } // while loop end

     } // if end
        var n:Int = 0
        for i in dbData
        {
            print("Value of Counter at Row " + String(n) + " = " + String(i.counter))
            n += 1
        }

    return dbData

   }
```

the outcome which I am receiving from running the above code is

```
Value of Counter at Row 0 = 8
Value of Counter at Row 1 = 8
Value of Counter at Row 2 = 8
Value of Counter at Row 3 = 8
Value of Counter at Row 4 = 8
```

the values are repeating in rows..

[the image of a table in database.. I am trying to fetch the value of column Counter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFN4G.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the QazaDB is a reference type (class) and because of that it's showing only the last assigned value. Probably you need to change your while loop like:

```
while sqlite3_step(queryStatement) == SQLITE_ROW
{
   let data = QazaDB()
   let counter = sqlite3_column_int(queryStatement, 0)
   data.counter = Int(counter)
   dbData.append(data)
} // while loop end
```

You can also change the QazaDB to a struct, which can also fix the issue.